# Do I generate additional effort when I replace the frontend-part of a Meteor app through a standalone javascript client using DDP?

Tags: javascript, meteor, socket.io, ionic-framework

I am planning on building a chat app with a mobile frontend and I wanted to use Meteor as my backend.

Regarding the client, I am currently evaluating between native apps and the Ionic-V2-approach.
IonicV1 worked well with Meteor, but I couldnt find anything on when a Meteor Package for V2 will be released, meaning I would need to use a standalone JS-DDP-client. On native platforms you also need a DDP-Client in the platforms language to make use of Meteor.

Does it generate additional effort to use Meteor only for the backend without using the meteor frontend, and do I lose the benefits of using Meteor with this approach?

Comment: Your question is a huge bait for opinion-based close votes. Please stick to pure facts, such as "Can the Meteor frontend be decoupled from its backend?". Avoid all kind of vocabulary that implies we should give you "advice", use vocabulary which makes us give you **facts**. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I changed my question. Also I think my question was not completely clear and I hope I could fix that, because I do not want not just to decouple, but instead use a completely standalone frontend js app. I hope I could point this out now.

Comment: "does it generate additional effort" ... "additional effort" being not quantifiable in any way, your question will still draw on experiences and opinions and is still a poor fit for SO.

Comment: I get your point, but am not sure on how I can rephrase the question to be not like that, because I tried out the scenario and it works and looks fine, but I cannot tell if I will face major problems in the future when things get more complicated, and wanted to know if somebody out there already tried this out and can tell me about his/her experiences. I dont know the direct problem, but want to know if there are major problems-by-design with the approach of using a separate frontend together with meteor (regarding authentication, security, database-access, etc) that I will have to consider.